# MySQL Multiple UPDATE SET

Tags: mysql, sql

I have many updates to make on a MySQL table.  Here's an example of the SQL queries:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_title` = replace(post_title, 'Im', 'I’m')

UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_title` = replace(post_title, 'Ill', 'I’ll')

UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_title` = replace(post_title, 'Id', 'I’d')
```

Will this query format work?  Also, how do I match the exact word to find?  For example:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_title` = replace(post_title, 'Id', 'I’d')
```

Will not only update Id to I'd but also Idle to I'dle,  I don't want that!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that query format should work. And in these specific cases with `I'm`, `I'll`, and `I'd`, there should always be a space following each word. Here's an idea...

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = replace(post_title, 'Id ', 'I’d ')
```